# A Until B and B after A not?

Tags: grammar, meaning

Can someone of you tell me if the following sentences is the same meaning or not?

" After she came to Korea, she learned Korean.

She didn't learn Korean until she came to Korea. "

For me, they sound the same..

Comment: Welcome to ELL. It's always an incentive for people to answer if you are more specific about where you think a problem might be. You say they sound the same and then you ask if they have the same meaning and if one of them is grammatically incorrect. What is it exactly that you want to know?

Comment: First of all, I want to know that these two sentences are the same meanings or not.

Answer (score 2):

There may, of course, be some subtext implied in certain situations by using one or the other, but taking them at face value they convey exactly the same information - that Korean was only learnt by a certain woman after her arrival in the ROK (or DPRK).

Comment: That's what I thought but others disagree with me. So I had to prove it. Thanks for your answer! ^^ I'm from ROK though.

Comment: I had guessed as much (not exactly a burgeoning internet community over the border), but since our hypothetical woman could be traveling to either, figured it was best to cover all the bases.